# Python custom sort by multiple factors

Tags: python, sorting

If I have a (python) list like so

```
my_list = [
    'Large Spearmint Bag Back',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Back',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Back',
    'Small Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Medium Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Family Shot',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Front',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Large Spearmint Bag Front',
]
```

You'll notice in the list there are sets of items, like so `Large Spearmint Bag Front` and `Large Spearmint Bag Back` where the only difference is one is the front and one is the back.  I need to sort these in alphabetical order, but have the front come before the backs so that the output would look like this:

```
[
    'Family Shot',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Front',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Back',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Back',
    'Large Spearmint Bag Front',
    'Large Spearmint Bag Back',
    'Medium Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Small Peppermint Bag Front'
]
```

I'm not even sure this is possible with the built in `sorted` function.  Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: So you want `sorted(my_list, key=lambda item: (item, item.split()[-1]))`?

Comment: You can downcase "B" in "Back", sort ("Back" will come after "Front") and then capitalize "Back". (UPD: did the opposite the first time I've read the post, lol)

Comment: You need to define a function to properly split the string into a tuple; from there it's fairly simple to convert that tuple into one whose natural comparison will be correct. The trick is splitting a string like `... Bag Front` into `('... Bag', 'Front')` while leaving `Family Shot` as `('Family Shot', '')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda item: (item.split()[:-1], 'Back' in item))
```

`item.split()[:-1]` returns all words but the last. `'Back' in item` returns `True` if `Back` is in string and `False` otherwise. Net effect is that we're substituting last word with True and False and then sort according to this key.

Comment: Doesn't `item.split()[:-1]` return all words but the last?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes sorry

Comment: Great solution.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to add a "special tag" with `a` before the "Front", then `sort` and remove the"special tag", The reason for "special tag" is to make sure it wont repeat in a word at the list.

**Code:**

```
my_list = [
    'Large Spearmint Bag Back',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Back',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Back',
    'Small Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Medium Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Family Shot',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Front',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Large Spearmint Bag Front',
]

my_list_edit = ["{}A-tag{}".format(word[:word.rfind('Front')], 'Front') if 'Front' in word else word for word in my_list]

my_list_edit = sorted(my_list_edit)

my_list_edit = [word.replace('A-tag', '')for word in my_list_edit]

print my_list_edit
```

**Output:**

```
['Family Shot',
 'Large Cinnamon Bag Front',
 'Large Cinnamon Bag Back',
 'Large Peppermint Bag Front',
 'Large Peppermint Bag Back',
 'Large Spearmint Bag Front',
 'Large Spearmint Bag Back',
 'Medium Peppermint Bag Front',
 'Small Peppermint Bag Front']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import  itemgetter
lf = [
    'Family Shot',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Front',
    'Large Cinnamon Bag Back',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Large Peppermint Bag Back',
    'Large Spearmint Bag Front',
    'Large Spearmint Bag Back',
    'Medium Peppermint Bag Front',
    'Small Peppermint Bag Front'
]

# find 'Family Shot', save into tuple, remove from list
ind_fam_shot = lf.index('Family Shot')
fam_shot=tuple(lf[ind_fam_shot].split())
lf.remove('Family Shot')

li = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.split()),lf))

li =  sorted(li,key=itemgetter(1))
li.insert(0,fam_shot)

for el in li:
print(el)

('Family', 'Shot')
('Large', 'Cinnamon', 'Bag', 'Front')
('Large', 'Cinnamon', 'Bag', 'Back')
('Large', 'Peppermint', 'Bag', 'Front')
('Large', 'Peppermint', 'Bag', 'Back')
('Medium', 'Peppermint', 'Bag', 'Front')
('Small', 'Peppermint', 'Bag', 'Front')
('Large', 'Spearmint', 'Bag', 'Front')
('Large', 'Spearmint', 'Bag', 'Back')
```